# Interface inherits from interface without specifying new member

Tags: c#, object-oriented-design

Is it some kind of bad design to have something like this:

```
public interface IFooStream
{
    long Length { get; }
    long Position {get; set;}
    //...
}

public interface IReadableFooStream<T> : IFooStream
{
    int Read(T[] buffer, int offset, int count);
}

public interface IByteStream : IReadableFooStream<byte>
{
}

public interface IFloatStream : IReadableFooStream<float>
{
}
```

How would you solve something like this? I definitely must have the IByteStream and the IFloatStream interface.

Comment: What is the reason you "definitely must have the IByteStream and the IFloatStream interface"?

Answer (score 2):

> I definitely must have the IByteStream and the IFloatStream interface.

Without a compelling reason, I definitely say you don't. Do you make a `ByteList` or a `FloatList`? No, you leave `List` be and let people parameterize it.

This sort of aliasing can *occasionally* be useful, but more often it is a code smell that your interface/class is *too* abstract (or doing too many things). You're allowing things to be parameterized to the n-th degree, and that is usually not needed.

> How would you solve something like this?

In my experience, an `IFooStream` isn't useful by itself. I would make a read stream, a write stream, and a combination *maaaaybe* with a base interface if/when I find I actually need it. Assuming of course that the .NET streams are somehow incapable of supplying the interface I need to do the work...

Comment: This is just a simplified example. But in reality I've got an audio library. The IByteStream (it is not the real name - don't wanted to make it complicated) represents any streams which provide raw data. The IFloatStream provides audio samples instead of raw data. I would like to split them both up into two defined interfaces. The IFooStream just connects both types since both got a length and a position,... But actually the IByteStream and the IFloatStream already exist as an essential part of the audio lib. So it would not make any sense to remove them + I really need them to know whether

Comment: an implementation provides raw data or provides samples.

Comment: -- so would you call it an indicator of bad design?

Answer (score 0):

> The IFooStream just connects both types since both got a length and a
>   position,... But actually the IByteStream and the IFloatStream already
>   exist as an essential part of the audio lib.

It sounds like the only other types in the lib that depend on `IFooStream` and `IReadableFooStream<T>` are `IByteStream` and `IFloatStream`. Those last two sound like the interesting ones that the rest of the lib use. If no other types actually depend on `IReadableFooStream<T>`, and it is there for the sake of inheritance, I agree that it smells.

> I really need them to know whether an implementation provides raw data
>   or provides samples.

So then, why not prefer composition over inheritance and call them what they are?

```
public interface IProvideRawStream
{
    IFooStream Stream { get; }
    int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);
}

public interface IProvideSampleStream
{
    IFooStream Stream { get; }
    int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count);
}
```

... or, if composition doesn't make sense in the API, what is wrong with having inheritance go only 1 level deep?

```
public interface IFooStream
{
    long Length { get; }
    long Position {get; set;}
    //...
}

public interface IProvideRawStream : IFooStream
{
    int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);
}

public interface IProvideSampleStream : IFooStream
{
    int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count);
}
```

Comment: Well composition is not an option. The second implementation is the current implementation. What would you think about removing the IReadableFooStream<T> and adding the generic read method to the IFooStream instead?